# Approximate ∫((e^x)/(x^x))dx

Tags: code-golf, math, calculus

You are to approximate the value of:

$$\int^I_0 \frac {e^x} {x^x} dx$$

Where your input is \$I\$.

## Rules

- You may not use any built-in integral functions.
- You may not use any built-in infinite summation functions.
- Your code must execute in a reasonable amount of time ( < 20 seconds on my machine)
- You may assume that input is greater than 0 but less than your language's upper limit.
- It may be any form of standard return/output.

You can verify your results at [Wolfram | Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+e%5Ex%2Fx%5Ex+from+0+to) (you can verify by concatenating your intended input to the linked query).

## Examples

(let's call the function `f`)

```
f(1) -> 2.18273
f(50) -> 6.39981
f(10000) -> 6.39981
f(2.71828) -> 5.58040
f(3.14159) -> 5.92228
```

Your answer should be accurate to `±.0001`.

Comment: @ThomasKwa Maximum for your language. I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says the last one rounds to `5.92228`

Comment: @Neil o-o Alrighty then, must've mistyped. Thanks!

Comment: I'll award 200 rep to the shortest valid answer in TI-BASIC that executes in <20 seconds on WabbitEmu at 100% speed.

Comment: @lirtosiast If you are still intent on following up on this bounty, you should post it [here](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5243/list-of-bounties-with-no-deadlines) instead.

Comment: @VoteToClose Done.

Answer (score 12):

## Julia, <s>79</s> <s>77</s> 38 bytes

```
I->sum(x->(e/x)^x,0:1e-5:min(I,9))/1e5
```

This is an anonymous function that accepts a numeric value and returns a float. To call it, assign it to a variable.

The approach here is to use a right Riemann sum to approximate the integral, which is given by the following formula:

$$\int_a^b f(x) dx \approx \sum f(x) \Delta x$$

In our case, \$a = 0\$ and \$b = I\$, the input. We divide the region of integration into \$n = 10^5\$ discrete portions, so \$∆x = \frac 1 n = 10^{-5}\$. Since this is a constant relative to the sum, we can pull this outside of the sum and simply sum the function evaluations at each point and divide by \$n\$.

The function is surprisingly well-behaved (plot from Mathematica):

[image: mathematicaplot]

Since the function evaluates nearly to 0 for inputs greater than about 9, we truncate the input to be \$I\$ if \$I\$ is less than 9, or 9 otherwise. This simplifies the calculations we have to do significantly.

Ungolfed code:

```
function g(I)
    # Define the range over which to sum. We truncate the input
    # at 9 and subdivide the region into 1e5 pieces.
    range = 0:1e-5:min(I,9)

    # Evaluate the function at each of the 1e5 points, sum the
    # results, and divide by the number of points.
    return sum(x -> (e / x)^x, range) / 1e5
end
```

Saved 39 bytes thanks to Dennis!

Comment: Isn't this also equivalent to: $\frac{t\sum_{k=0}^{n}(f(a+kt)+f(a+(k+1)t))}{2}$? That seems slightly simpler of an algorithm to use.

Comment: `10^4` can be written as `1e4`.

Comment: @VoteToClose Ended up taking a different approach

Comment: @RainerP. Heh, right. Thanks.

Comment: The asymptotic value of the integral is $6.39981...$.  The value $6.39981... - 10^{-4}$ is first attained at $I = 7.91399...$, so you can truncate at $8$ instead of $9$ to save a little time.

Answer (score 10):

## Jelly, <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 17 bytes

```
ð«9×R÷øȷ5µØe÷*×ḢS
```

This borrows the clever *truncate at 9* trick from [@AlexA.'s answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71314), and uses a [right Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum#Right_Riemann_Sum) to estimate the corresponding integral.

Truncated test cases take a while, but are fast enough on [Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=w7DCqznDl1LDt8O4yLc1wrXDmGXDtyrDl-G4olM&input=&args=MTA&debug=on)

#### How it works

```
ð«9×R÷øȷ5µØe÷*×ḢS  Main link. Input: I

      øȷ5          Niladic chain. Yields 1e5 = 100,000.

ð                  Dyadic chain. Left argument: I. Right argument: 1e5.
 «9                Compute min(I, 9).
   ×               Multiply the minimum with 1e5.
    R              Range; yield [1, 2, ..., min(I, 9) * 1e5] or [0] if I < 1e-5.
     ÷             Divide the range's items by 1e5.
                   This yields r := [1e-5, 2e-5, ... min(I, 9)] or [0] if I < 1e-5.

         µ         Monadic chain. Argument: r
          Øe÷      Divide e by each element of r.
             *     Elevate the resulting quotients to the corresponding elements,
                   mapping t -> (e/t) ** t over r.
                   For the special case of r = [0], this yields [1], since
                   (e/0) ** 0 = inf ** 0 = 1 in Jelly.
              ×Ḣ   Multiply each power by the first element of r, i.e., 1e-5 or 0.
                S  Add the resulting products.
```

Comment: Oh, alright. Left-hand rule is how it's referred to in AP Calculus classes. :P Coolio.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that name, but the left-hand rule probably uses the left endpoints. My code uses the right ones.

Comment: (~-.-)~ It's some form of handed rule. xD

Answer (score 4):

### ES7, 78 bytes

```
i=>[...Array(n=2e3)].reduce(r=>r+Math.exp(j+=i)/j**j,0,i>9?i=9:0,i/=n,j=-i/2)*i
```

This uses the rectangle rule with 2000 rectangles, which (at least for the examples) seem to produce a sufficiently accurate answer, but the accuracy could easily be increased if necessary. It has to use the 9 trick otherwise the accuracy drops off for large values.

73 byte version that uses rectangles of width ~0.001 so it doesn't work above ~700 because Math.exp hits Infinity:

```
i=>[...Array(n=i*1e3|0)].reduce(r=>r+Math.exp(j+=i)/j**j,0,i/=n,j=-i/2)*i
```

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 26 bytes

```
9hX<t1e6XK:K/*ttZebb^/sK/*
```

This approximates the integral as a Riemann sum. As argued by Alex, we can truncate the integration interval at approximately 9 because the function values are very small beyond that.

The maximum value of the function is less than 3, so a step of about 1e-5 should be enough to obtain the desired accuracy. So for the maximum input 9 we need about 1e6 points.

This takes about 1.5 seconds in the online compiler, for any input value.

[**Try it online**!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OWhYPHQxZTZYSzpLLyp0dFplYmJeL3NLLyo&input=My4xNDE1OQ)

```
9hX<         % input number, and limit to 9
t            % duplicate
1e6XK:       % generate vector [1,2,...,1e6]. Copy 1e6 to clipboard K
K/*          % divide by 1e6 and multiply by truncated input. This gives 
             % a vector with 1e6 values of x from 0 to truncated input
ttZe         % duplicate twice. Compute exp(x)
bb^          % rotate top three elements of stack twice. Compute x^x
/            % divide to compute exp(x)/x^x
s            % sum function values
K/*          % multiply by the step, which is the truncated input divided
             % by 1e6
```

Answer (score 2):

## [golflua](http://mniip.com/misc/conv/golflua/), 83 chars

I'll admit it: it took my a while to figure out the `min(I,9)` trick Alex presented allowed computing arbitrarily high numbers because the integral converged by then.

```
\f(x)~M.e(x)/x^x$b=M.mn(I.r(),9)n=1e6t=b/n g=0.5+f(b/2)~@k=1,n-1g=g+f(k*t)$I.w(t*g)
```

An ungolfed Lua equivalent would be

```lua
function f(x)
   return math.exp(x)/x^x
end

b=math.min(io.read("*n"),9)
n=1e6
t=b/n
g=0.5+f(b/2)

for k=1,n-1 do
   g=g+f(k*t)
end
io.write(t*g)
```

Comment: And by "a while" I mean about 10 minutes. And that was entirely because I didn't actually read Alex's comment that explains it, just saw it in the code.

Answer (score 2):

## Perl 6, <s>90</s> 55 bytes

```perl6
{my \x=1e5;sum ((e/$_*x)**($_/x)/x for 1..min($_,9)*x)}
```

**usage**

```perl6
my &f = {my \x=1e5;sum ((e/$_*x)**($_/x)/x for 1..min($_,9)*x)}

f(1).say;       # 2.1827350239231
f(50).say;      # 6.39979602775846
f(10000).say;   # 6.39979602775846
f(2.71828).say; # 5.58039854392816
f(3.14159).say; # 5.92227602782184
```

It's late and I need to sleep, I'll see if I can get this any shorter tomorrow.

EDIT: Managed to get it quite a bit shorter after seeing @DenkerAffe 's method.

Comment: I like how it says $h*t in there. :D

Answer (score 2):

## Python 2, <s>94</s> 76 bytes

Thanks to @Dennis for saving me 18 bytes!

```python
lambda I,x=1e5:sum((2.71828/i*x)**(i/x)/x for i in range(1,int(min(I,9)*x)))
```

[Try it online with testcases!](https://repl.it/Bk6w/2)

Using the rectangle method for the approximation. Using a rectangle width of 0.0001 which gives me the demanded precision. Also truncating inputs greater 9 to prevent memory errors with very big inputs.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, <s>34</s> 29 bytes

Saved 5 Bytes with some help from @Dennis!

```
J^T5smcc^.n1d^ddJmcdJU*hS,Q9J
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%5ET5smcc%5E.n1d%5EddJmcdJU*hS%2CQ9J&input=1&test_suite_input=1%0A50%0A10000%0A2.71828%0A3.14159&debug=0)

#### Explanation

Same algorithm as in [my Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71346/49110).

```
J^T5smcc^.n1d^ddJmcdJU*hS,Q9J        # Q=input
J^T5                                 # set J so rectangle width *10^5
                       hS,Q9         # truncate inputs greater 9
                 mcdJU/     J        # range from zero to Input in J steps
     mcc^.n1d^ddJ                    # calculate area for each element in the list
    s                                # Sum all areas and output result
```

Comment: You can save a few bytes by assigning `J` to `^T5` and swapping multiplication with division by `J`. Also, the truncation can be done with `hS,Q9`.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, did not think about that. Also the sorting trick is nice, I was just searching for `min` ^^

Answer (score 2):

## Vitsy, 39 bytes

Thought I might as well give my own contribution. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ This uses the Left-Hand Riemann Sum estimation of integrals.

```
D9/([X9]1a5^D{/V}*0v1{\[EvV+DDv{/}^+]V*

D9/([X9]               Truncation trick from Alex A.'s answer.
D                      Duplicate input.
 9/                    Divide it by 9.
   ([  ]               If the result is greater than 0
     X9                Remove the top item of the stack, and push 9.

1a5^D{/V}*0v0{         Setting up for the summation.
1                      Push 1.
 a5^                   Push 100000.
    D                  Duplicate the top item of the stack.
     {                 Push the top item of the stack to the back.
      /                Divide the top two items of the stack. (1/100000)
       V               Save it as a global variable.
                       Our global variable is ∆x.
        }              Push the bottom item of the stack to the top.
         *             Multiply the top two items.
                       input*100000 is now on the stack.
          0v           Save 0 as a temporary variable.
            0          Push 1.
             {         Push the bottom item of the stack to the top.
                       input*100000 is now the top of the stack.

\[EvV+DDv{/}^+]        Summation.
\[            ]        Loop over this top item of the stack times.
                       input*100000 times, to be exact.
  E                    Push Math.E to the stack.
   v                   Push the temporary variable to the stack.
                       This is the current value of x.
    V+                 Add ∆x.
      DD               Duplicate twice.
        v              Save the temporary variable again.
         {             Push the top item of the stack to the back.
          /            Divide the top two items.
                       e/x
           }           Push the top item back to the top of the stack.
            ^          Put the second to top item of the stack to the power of the top item.
                       (e/x)^x
             +         Add that to the current sum.

V*                     Multiply by ∆x
```

This leaves the sum on the top of the stack. The try it online link below has `N` on the end to show you the result.

[Try it Online!](http://vitsy.tryitonline.net/#code=RDkvKFtYOV0xYTVeRHsvVn0qMHYwe1xbRXZWK0REdnsvfV4rXVYqTg&input=&args=OQ)